# Is there a Contains function in SAS Hive (Hadoop)?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas, hiveql, contains

I'm needing help again

Is there an equivalent to the Contains function in SAS Hadoop (explicit SQL Pass through) ?

E.g. an alternative version to:

```
WHEN a.DESCRIPTION NOT CONTAINS "XXX"
```

I attempted using:

```
When (array_contains(a.DESCRIPTION ,'XXX') = FALSE)
```

But that does not work.

Any help most welcome!

Comment: Array_contains works on Array to check particular element is there or not, I guess you can use like and not like in Hive for your purpose

Comment: or even a instr can work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kiran for suggesting the instr function.... looks like it does what I needed

So I used to get what I wanted:

```
When instr(a.DESCRIPTION, 'XXX') = 0 Then 1
```

Mayank.... Thanks for your suggestion, I'll investigate this function later on

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `rlike(regular_expression)`.

```
WHERE some_col RLIKE '*abc*|*pqr*|*xyz*'
```

For negative results, put a `NOT` before `RLIKE`.

Let me know if this works.